# Inheritance and Polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, types, polymorphism

Suppose I have two classes as following:

```
public class Button{
       public void onClick(){ do something...}}

public class imageButton extends Button{
       public void onClick(){...}
       public void setImage(Image img){...}}
```

I know that I can declare a variable like this

```
Button btn1 = new imageButton();
```

or

```
imageButton btn2 = new imageButton():
```

but what are the differences? What exactly is the datatype of the first instance? If I used the first instance, why btn1.setImage(Image img) will give me an error?

Thank you.

Comment: *If I used the first instance, why btn1.setImage(Image img) will give me an error?* Because `setImage()` resides in `imageButton` class and not `Button`.

Comment: how do we read the this line? `Button btn1 = new imageButton();`

Comment: You are creating a object of class `Button` named `btn1` which is initialized with a new object of class `imageButton`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Button btn1 = new imageButton();`
>   What exactly is the datatype of the first instance?

It is an `imageButton`, but you will only have access to the methods defined in `Button` when using the reference `btn1`. If you want to treat it as an `imageButton`, you'll have to cast it.

> If I used the first instance, why btn1.setImage(Image img) will give me an error?

Because you declared that you want to treat the object as a `Button`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I still have one uncertainty. Is there any advantage/disadvantage in using this declaration?

Comment: @Learnandpractice That is a big question with many answers. The first thing that pops into my mind is to use `Button` (or what ever the most general type is in a particular situation) unless you know you will need to use specific methods from `imageButton` (or some other specific subclass). This will make it easier to change the code to switch to `EvenBetterImageButton` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

with Button btn1 = new imageButton(); you are creating an instance of imageButton but since you datatype is Button it will only take the properties that are included in Button, you cant use btn1.setImage() because btn1 is a Button Type.